# Programmatically checking if a package is installed in the Lazarus IDE

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus, pascalscript

For one of my class libraries I would like to provide a simplified workaround code if a certain package is unavailable.

Is there a recommended way to check from code, which packages are installed in the IDE? Compiler or IDE defines would be preferred, but a solution in Pascal Script would be fine as well.

Comment: You mean, in a designtime package? Any other code can't access the IDE.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Thanks, but it would be useful for any package, not only design-time. Unfortunately, the documentation for Pascal Script is sparse. Does it support the editor only?

Comment: Pascal script is Lazarus(IDE) only, so won't do anything from code.   But maybe in the IDE you can set a define to be passed to the compiler based on pascalscript somehow, but that is not my field of expertise

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I see that this is obviously impossible in the current version.